# continous function of almost everywhere convergence functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We were given the following problem in a probability theory class:

for $i = 1 \dots k$ Let:

$$X_n ^ {(i)} \rightarrow X ^ {(i)}$$

where the convergence is in probability or any finite measure. Prove that for any continous function $f : \mathbb{R} ^ k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have:

$$f(X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)}) \rightarrow f(X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)})$$

I was thinking of a proof in the following way:

We need to show $\mu(|f(X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)}) - f(X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)})| > \epsilon)$ converges to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. To show this I take some $\delta > 0$ so that :

$d((X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)}), (X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)})) < \delta \Rightarrow 
d(f(X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)}), f(X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)})) < \epsilon$

So if $d(f(X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)}), f(X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)})) > \epsilon$ there exists some index $i$ so that $d(X_n ^ {(i)}, X ^ {(i)}) > \frac {\delta}{k}$ Since $\mu(d(X_n ^ {(i)}, X ^ {(i)}) > \frac {\delta}{k})$ tends to zero we get into the conclusion that  $\mu(|f(X ^ {(1)}, \dots, X ^ {(k)}) - f(X_n ^ {(1)}, \dots, X_n ^ {(k)})| > \epsilon)$ tends to zero.

But there is probably something wrong with this approach Since I didn't use the finiteness of the measure and the proof of the book is way too complicated that this one. Can anyone see the problem in the proof?

Comment: Your approach would work if $f$ was uniformly continuous, or the limit of each $X_n^{(i)}$ was a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach. Let $g_n(\omega):=f(X_n^{(1)}(\omega),\ldots,X_n^{(k)}(\omega))$. Then $g_n\to g\equiv f(X^{(1)},\ldots,X^{(k)})$ if and only if every subsequence of $\{g_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging to $g$ a.e. (This requires the finiteness of $\mu$.) The existence of such a subsequence is guaranteed by the continuity of $f$ and the convergence of each $X_n^{(i)}$ in $\mu$-measure.